# Vincular subdominio de route 53 a subdominio de hosting compartido

Tags: dns, aws, amazon

resulta que tengo un proyecto en amazon y para dicho proyecto tengo un dominio (midominio.com.mx)funcionando con route 53. Ahí hace toda la mágia, configuro el balanceador que a la vez va a varias instancias, etc,etc,etc.

Se me ocurrió la fantástica idea de crear un blog, pero como tengo varios servidores, no quiero tener conflictos con ello y gastar dinero apuntando todos mis archivos al servicio de bucket s3 para que todo esté sincronizado.  Entonces para ello compré otro dominio (midominio.mx) y lo vinculé con un hosting compartid, ahí monté mi blog de wordpress y todo de maravilla, el problema es que, el proyecto y el blog (obviamente) funcionan bajo dominios diferentes.

me preguntaba si pudo hacer lo siguiente:
Crear un subdominio en route 53-> blog.miproyecto.com.mx y apuntarlo para que trabaje con el subdominio de mi hosting compartido -> blog.miproyecto.mx (no que redireccione, si no que el usuario final no se de cuenta que ambos proyectos están en dominios (servidores) separados.

¿Esto es posible? y si es posible ¿Cual sería el procedimiento?

Actualmene tengo  el blog creado en mi otro dominio y en route 53 tengo creado un subdominio apuntando a la ip de mi  servidor compartido, pero no funciona :( la verdad no se nisiquiera si esto es posible >.<
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Primero, no debiera ser necesario apuntar tu subdominio `blog.midominio.com.mx` a una IP. Puede simplemente ser un **CNAME** de `blog.midominio.mx`. Con eso el registro en Route53 "seguirá" al dominio aunque lo muevas de un hosting a otro.

Segundo, tu hosting compartido (como su nombre indica) tiene a muchos clientes en una máquina. Esa máquina tiene una sola IP (aunque puede tener más, pero digamos que es una sola). Para saber a qué sitio enviar cada request, la máquina tiene distintos **vhosts**, que básicamente mapean un host (dominio o subdominio, en este caso) a un document_root.

- El request dice blog.midominio.mx? Lo mando a /var/www/midominio
- El request dice www.pagina.com? Lo mando a /var/www/pagina
- El request dice blog.midominio.com.mx? No conozco ese host. Le muestro una página genérica

(este es un ejemplo de un hosting compartido muy inseguro, pero te ilustra cómo enrutan las peticiones)

Por ese lado, tendrías que ver si puedes añadir dominios a tu cuenta en el hosting compartido, ya sea en tu dashboard o con un ticket de soporte.

Tercero, si tu blog está en wordpress creo que tengo malas noticias, porque wordpress siempre intentará redirigir al dominio oficial que figura en el panel de administración.